# How to declare generic method with parameter of protocol array or protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, swift5

The result I want is:
The generic type can be an array or a separate protocol,
The return value is also judged based on the generic type

This code is not compiled:

```swift
protocol HandyJSON {
    
}

extension HandyJSON {
    static func deserialize(from dic: [String:Any]?) -> HandyJSON? {
        //return HandyJSON?
    }
}

extension Array where Element: HandyJSON {

    static func deserialize(from arr: [Any]?) -> [Element?]? {
        //return [HandyJSON?]
    }
}

class Person : HandyJSON {
    
    var name : String?
    var age : Int?
}


struct Requests {

    // T can be a protocal, and [object]
    static func post<T>(decodeType:T.Type) where T : HandyJSON, T : [HandyJSON] -> T {
        
        //send reques...
        //let data = resp.data
        
        var respData : Any?
        
//        if let data = respData as? [String : Any] {
//
//        }
//
//        if let data = respData as? [Any] {
//
//        }
        
        
        //T is HandyJSON
        if decodeType is HandyJSON.Type {
            
            return T.deserialize(from: (respData as? [String : Any]))
            //or? -> HandyJSON
            //return decodeType.deserialize(from: NSDictionary?)
        }

        //T is [HandyJSON]
        if decodeType is [HandyJSON].Type {
           return T.deserialize(from: (respData as? [Any]))
            //or?
            //return decodeType.deserialize(from: [Any]?)
        }
    }
}
```

Error: `Type 'T' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type '([HandyJSON]) -> T'`

Whether generic can be defined as Array, Some object Array

If these methods are implemented, I can use it like this

```swift
class vc : UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let somebody : Person? = Requests.post(decodeType:Person.Type) // Person Object
        
        let arr : [Person?]? = Requests.post(decodeType:[Person].Type)
        
    }
}
```

Or describe like this

`T can be a object or array that implement HandyJSON protocol`

```swift
func post<T:HandyJSON | [HandyJSON]>(arg:T.Type) -> T {
    //
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish but you can make Array and Dictionary conform to HandyJSON and then simply declare `static func post<T: HandyJSON>(type: T.Type) -> T? {`

Comment: The code does not compile anyway. What is `decodeType`? And the return type must be right after the closing parenthesis. By the way this kind of type check at runtime is very *unswifty*

Comment: You will need two methods either array or element, or you have to use `Any` and to `as?` casting